# How to copy a table from an outlook email and store it in a variable

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am using Win32com.client to read email content from Outlook, but one of the emails contains a table. When I read the table using msg.body() The table is stored in a string format and does not look like a table. The whole email body is stored like a string including the table. Is there a way that I can recognize this table while parsing through the email body using Win32com and what good way can be used to read this table and store it in a variable to look like an actual table.

Note: I am using python to do so

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and congrads on your first post! Please review a few things first: [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It would be helpful if you provided the data you are having problems with, and what you have done so far to parse it/what specific problems you had doing that

Answer (score 0):

Read the `HTMLBody` property instead and parse out the `<table>` elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After detecting the place of the table, do you have any suggestions on how to copy the actual table into a variable?

Comment: That really depends on what you mean by "variable". One way or another, you'd need to parse the data to extract the information.